# Magento display internal 500 error when custom order create with upload image

Tags: custom-action, magento-1.7, internal-server-error

I am create custom order in magento and add custom product in cart.

But when i try to create custom order with `static image upload`..Before this is all run successfully.. before some days i got error below..

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

The problem is on the server side, not with your browser or the address. Most probably, a certain service (e.g., Tomcat engine) is down. Please contact your webmaster.
```

What i need to do.. please send me solutions if any one asap.